# Add an empty line prior to another matched line in jq?

Tags: json, stream, edit, jq

Say I have a raw input like the following:

````
"```"
"include <stdio.h>"
"..."
"```"
"''some example''"
"*bob"
"**bob"
"*bob"
````

And I'd like to add a blank line right before the "*bob":

````
"```"
"include <stdio.h>"
"..."
"```"
"''some example''"
""
"*bob"
"**bob"
"*bob"
````

Can this be done with jq?

Comment: it's much easier with sed

Comment: Why are you using jq? You're dealing with strings of data, there probably isn't even any json within that. There are better tools for that.

Comment: @JeffMercado Because I eventually need to transform it into JSON data, and jq offers pretty tools for that...now maybe it isn't the best tool for reading in the file, but it's great for outputting the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution which uses the [`-s`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) (slurp) option

```
.[: .[["*bob"]][0]] + ["\n"] + .[.[["*bob"]][0]:] | .[]
```

that's a little unreadable but we can make it better with a few functions:

```
  def firstbob:  .[["*bob"]][0] ;
  def beforebob: .[: firstbob ] ;
  def afterbob:  .[ firstbob :] ;

    beforebob + ["\n"] + afterbob
  | .[]
```

if the above filter is in `filter.jq` and the sample data is in `data` then

```
$ jq -Ms -f filter.jq data
```

produces

````
"```"
"include <stdio.h>"
"..."
"```"
"''some example''"
"\n"
"*bob"
"**bob"
"*bob"
````

One issue with this approach is that `beforebob` and `afterbob` won't quite work as you probably want if `"*bob"` is not in the input.  The easiest way to address that is with an if guard:

```
    if firstbob then beforebob + ["\n"] + afterbob else . end
  | .[]
```

with that the input will be unaltered if `"*bob"` is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but to do so efficiently you'd effectively need jq 1.5 or higher:

```
foreach inputs as $line (0; 
  if $line == "*bob" then . + 1 else . end;
  if . == 1 then "" else empty end,
    $line)
```

Don't forget to use the -n command-line option!